# how to shift a git branch from one base to other base

Tags: git

I have branch called 'release-1.25.0', i created one more branch to fix this issue. (git add -b MS-12345 upstream/release-1.25.0 --no-track)
My Fix branch = MS-12345

Later My project has released a new branch called 'develop', now i want to move the MS-12345 branch to develop, so that in my Pull Request it should list only the changes which i made to fix the issue.

As of now it is showing some extra files that are in develop, but not in release-1.25.0 branch.

Please suggest me is there any away ? other than recreating the branch(MS-12345) under develop and cherry pick the changes.Before recreating i will delete my existing branch

Comment: Look into rebasing, `git rebase`.

Answer (score 0):

This will be handled by `rebase`, and specifically by using the `--onto` switch. In your case, this should do it:

`git rebase --onto develop release-1.25.0 MS-12345`

That order of arguments is "new branch to base off of", "current branch based off of", "the branch to be rebased", so make sure the arguments are correct for your scenario.

Relevant documentation is here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase
(search for `onto` on that page)